# AdminLTE Pagination - Where to Start?

Tags: php, adminlte

I'm building a web database application in PHP PDO using the AdminLTE template and Booststrap 3.
I need to add pagination to my application (as I have a large amount of records) and have a limit of 25 records per page. I am fairly new at programming and have no idea where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
  $content = '<div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="box box-danger">
                  <div class="box-header">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Members List</h3>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.box-header -->
                  <div class="box-body">
                    <table id="members" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                      <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Residential Address</th>
                        <th>Mailing Address</th>
                        <th>Precinct</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Ethnicity</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Party</th>
                        <th>Race</th>
                        <th>Phone Number</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                      </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      </tbody>
                      <tfoot>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Residential Address</th>
                        <th>Mailing Address</th>
                        <th>Precinct</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Ethnicity</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Party</th>
                        <th>Race</th>
                        <th>Phone Number</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                      </tr>
                      </tfoot>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.box-body -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.box -->
              </div>
            </div>';
  include('../master.php');
?>
<!-- page script -->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../api/member/read.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var response="";
            for(var user in data){
                response += "<tr>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].name+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].residential_address+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].mailing_address+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].precinct+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].age+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].ethnicity+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].gender+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].party+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].race+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].phone+"</td>"+
                "<td><a href='update.php?id="+data[user].id+"'>Edit</a> | <a href='#' onClick=Remove('"+data[user].id+"')>Remove</a></td>"+
                "</tr>";
            }
            $(response).appendTo($("#members"));
        }
    });
  });
  function Remove(id){
    var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the selected member from the database?"); 
    if (result == true) { 
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: '../api/member/delete.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert(result.responseText);
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result['status'] == true) {
                    alert("The member was successfully removed from the database.");
                    window.location.href = '/ccrp/members';
                }
                else {
                    alert(result['message']);
                }
            }
        });
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Your data is in a table, I recommend using the [tabletables](https://datatables.net/) jquery class, it has pagination built into the table along with a search box etc. It also has a style you can use [for bootstrap](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap). Doing pagination yourself is probably quite a bit more difficult than using this class, it's not really something that is answerable here.

Comment: Well, first, it seems weird to me that you are using an ajax request to gather the information for your table. Why not get it all with PHP and build the table during page load instead of after? Your use of Ajax with the remove button seems to be right on target, pretty much what it's made for, but building the table that way is weird to me.

Comment: Also, it's generally much better to keep HTML as HTML, instead of echoing it all as PHP. What is `master.php`?

Comment: `master.php` is the file that describes the layout of the entire application. All of the project files are refrerencing it. All of its code is HTML other than a single PHP line that grabs the content from the index page, which is the code shown above.

Comment: If it were me, I would have all of the code you have above as plain HTML (not echoing it with PHP). Then, in the `tbody` of the table, you'd have a PHP loop which fills in all of the rows of the table. At that point, using datatables is as simple as including the `.js` file and initializing it with `$('#members').DataTable();`

Comment: Another thing you may want to look into is a PHP framework, I feel like your `master.php` page is sort of acting as one, but not quite. There are hundreds of PHP frameworks, but I would personally recommend the one I created (of course I would) called [Grump-Free-Framework](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/grump-free-framework)